# Read data from files using textscan & plot histogram/ecdf using plotyy

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I try to read a text files with 20x20 data into variable C, and attempt to plot a histogram on the left Y-axes, and a ecdf/ksdensity on the right X-axes.

Using textscan, the data is read into a 400x1 array. However, when I tried to call plotyy to plot histogram, the code belows return

```
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths. 

Error in pt (line 11)
axes = plotyy(x,C{1},x,C{1});
```

I guess it is due to C{1}. But have no clue on how to resolve it. I am new to matlab, would anyone point out the correct way to perform the above operations?

```
fid = fopen('t1_error.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%.3f');            
fclose(fid);

disp(C{1});

x = -1:7;    % <-- change to x = length(C{1});  then histogram is plotted.
axes = plotyy(x,C{1},x,C{1});
hold on
hist(axes(1), C{1}, x);
ylim(axes(1),'auto');
set(axes(1),'mode','auto');
hold off
```

Comment: x has length 9, how long is C{1}? I guess it's 200? It must be of same length though. Why use plotyy if you are just plotting one vector? Try x = 1:200.

Comment: arh, the histogram is shown after I change x=1:400. However, my initial intention is to plot two graphs in single plot: X:error rate, Y1 (left-axes, histogram):probability,   Y2(right-axes, line): ecdf.

Before this I tried to plot a standalone histogram with the code below.
%     x_step = -1:0.1:7;
%     hist(C{1}, x_step);
%     xlabel('Relative Error');
%     ylabel('Probability');

Comment: So the code in the question is not the latest one? Can you please update the question such that it shows the x = 1:400 change you made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of `x` does not equal the length of `C{1}`. Try `x = 1:length(C{1})` or `x = -1:8/length(C{1}):7`.